# How to find which variable is causing RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to create an extremely simple network with a GRUcell layer to perform the following task: a cue is given in one of two locations. After T timesteps, the agent must learn to take a particular action at the opposite location.

I get the following error when trying to compute backward gradients:

> RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has
>   been modified by an inplace operation.

One problem is that I don't fully understand which piece of my code is performing the inplace operation.

I have read other posts on stackoverflow and on the pytorch forum, which all suggest using the `.clone()` operation. I've peppered it all over my code anywhere I think it could conceivably make a difference, but I haven't had success.

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.gru    = nn.GRUCell(2,50) # GRU layer taking 2 inputs (L or R), has 50 units
        self.actor  = nn.Linear(50,2)  # Linear Actor layer with 2 outputs, takes GRU as input
        self.critic = nn.Linear(50,1)  # Linear Critic layer with 1 output, takes GRU as input

    def forward(self, s, h):
        h  = self.gru(s,h)  # give the input and previous hidden state to the GRU layer
        c  = self.critic(h) # estimate the value of the current state
        pi = F.softmax(self.actor(h),dim=1) # calculate the policy 
        return (h,c,pi)

    def backward_rollout(self, gamma, R_t, c_t, t):
        R_t[0,t] = gamma*R_t[0,t+1].clone()
        # calculate the reward prediction error
        Delta_t[0,t] = c_t[0,t].clone() - R_t[0,t].clone()

        #calculate the loss for the critic 
        crit = c_t[0,t].clone()
        ret  = R_t[0,t].clone()
        Value_l[0,t] = F.smooth_l1_loss(crit,ret)


###################################
# Run a trial

# parameters
N      = 1   # number of trials to run
T      = 10   # number of time-steps in a trial
gamma  = 0.98 # temporal discount factor

# for each trial
for n in range(N):   
    sample  = np.random.choice([0,1],1)[0] # pick the sample input for this trial
    s_t     = torch.zeros((1,2,T))   # state at each time step

    h_0     = torch.zeros((1,50))    # initial hidden state
    h_t     = torch.zeros((1,50,T))  # hidden state at each time step

    c_t     = torch.zeros((1,T))    # critic at each time step
    pi_t    = torch.zeros((1,2,T))  # policy at each time step

    R_t     = torch.zeros((1,T))  # return at each time step
    Delta_t = torch.zeros((1,T))  # difference between critic and true return at each step
    Value_l = torch.zeros((1,T))  # value loss

    # set the input (state) vector/tensor
    s_t[0,sample,0] = 1.0 # set first time-step stimulus
    s_t[0,0,-1]     = 1.0 # set last time-step stimulus
    s_t[0,1,-1]     = 1.0 # set last time-step stimulus

    # step through the trial
    for t in range(T):  
        # run a forward step
        state = s_t[:,:,t].clone()
        if t is 0:
            (hidden_state, critic, policy) = net(state, h_0)

        else:
            (hidden_state, critic, policy) = net(state, h_t[:,:,t-1])

        h_t[:,:,t]  = hidden_state.clone()
        c_t[:,t]    = critic.clone()
        pi_t[:,:,t] = policy.clone()

    # select an action using the policy
    action = np.random.choice([0,1], 1, p = policy[0,:].detach().numpy()) 
    #action = int(np.random.uniform() < pi[0,1])

    # compare the action to the sample
    if action is sample:
        r = 0
        print("WRONG!")
    else:
        r = 1
        print("RIGHT!")

    #h_t_old = h_t
    #s_t_old = s_t

    # step backwards through the trial to calculate gradients
    R_t[0,-1]     = r
    Delta_t[0,-1] = c_t[0,-1].clone() - r
    Value_l[0,-1] = F.smooth_l1_loss(c_t[0,-1],R_t[0,-1]).clone()

    for t in np.arange(T-2,-1,-1): #backwards rollout 
        net.backward_rollout(gamma, R_t, c_t, t)

    Vl = Value_l.clone().sum()#calculate total loss

    Vl.backward() #calculate the derivatives 
    opt.step() #update the weights
    opt.zero_grad() #zero gradients before next trial
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `anomaly_detection` to pinpoint the exact offending in-place operation: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/15803

`Value_l[0,-1] =` and similar are in-place operations. You can sidestep the check by doing `Value_l.data[0,-1] =`, but this is not stored in the computational graph and may be a bad idea. A relevant discussion is here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-get-around-in-place-operation-error-if-index-leaf-variable-for-gradient-update/14554

Comment: The example given here points directly to a problem line. When I use this in my code, I get an error that I don't know how to make sense of. The last line of which is: 
File "<ipython-input-8-6b90cd25cafd>", line 63, in <module>
    Value_l[0,-1] = F.smooth_l1_loss(c_t[0,-1],R_t[0,-1]).clone()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2114, in smooth_l1_loss
    ret = torch._C._nn.smooth_l1_loss(expanded_input, expanded_target, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction))

Comment: There is also a comment on this issue: the anomaly detection will not necessarily point you at the inplace operation that caused the failure. Instead, it will point you at the operation that could not compute its gradient in the backward pass. The inplace operation to blame may occur anywhere after that, modifying one of the tensors that participated in the line found by the anomaly detection.

How do I find which is the offending in place operation? Or what is a suitable workaround?